# Shell script to replace string dynamically

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a shell script for linux which takes argument as port no.
inside file following is a line which needs to be updated:

```
define('NO_OF_PORTS',10);
```

I need to replace that 10 by the argument passed.
But this should be dynamic, like next time I pass new port no it must get updated.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
s="define('NO_OF_PORTS',10);"
n=25
sed "s/\('NO_OF_PORTS',\)[0-9]*/\1$n/" <<< "$s"
define('NO_OF_PORTS',25);
```

To change inline in the file use:

```
sed -i.bak "s/\('NO_OF_PORTS',\)[0-9]*/\1$n/" file
```

Comment: Sorry I think I'm the one who's making mistakes ><

Comment: Well I think I've made a mistake again.. There _is_ a mistake: `s='define('NO_OF_PORTS',10);'` is not equivalent to `s='define('\''NO_OF_PORTS'\'',10);'` (or `s="define('NO_OF_PORTS',10);"`), while I think here it shall be the later ones but not the one you're using.

Comment: you eliminated single quotes around NO_OF_PORTS in your result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed in the script to edit the file

```
sed -i s/NO_OF_PORTS\',[0-9]*/NO_OF_PORTS\',$1/ $2
```

Answer (score 0):

1.txt has

```
define('NO_OF_PORTS',19)
```

shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1
sed -i -r '/NO_OF_PORTS/ s/'[0-9]+'/'$1'/g' 1.txt
```

run

```
linux:/home/test # ./replace_port.sh 78
linux:/home/test # cat 1.txt
define('NO_OF_PORTS',78)
```